# Install newer packages without conflicting with core-recommended?

Tags: 9, composer

Is there a way to install third party packages without conflicting with core-recommended? Example:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - spatie/ignition[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.2] require symfony/console ^5.4|^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v5.4.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev].
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console v5.4.2.
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console v5.4.1.
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console v5.4.0.
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console v5.4.0-RC1.
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console v5.4.0-BETA1.
    - symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 conflicts with symfony/console 5.4.x-dev.
    - symfony/console[v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.1.x-dev] conflict with symfony/process v4.4.35.
    - drupal/core-recommended 9.3.2 requires symfony/http-kernel v4.4.35 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v4.4.35].
    - drupal/core-recommended 9.3.2 requires symfony/process v4.4.35 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.35].
    - drupal/core-recommended is locked to version 9.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/ignition ^1.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/ignition[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].
```

I am guessing in this particular instance no, since Symfony 5/6.x is not coming until Drupal 10.

Comment: Would also love to know this. Stops me installing the latest version of phpdotenv which is just annoying. I suspect the answer is "no" because core-recommended locks the packages to specific versions, and Composer wouldn't work very well if it had a way to just ignore the dependencies

Comment: Isn't the version locking [the point of core-recommended](https://github.com/drupal/core-recommended#drupalcore-recommended)? If you don't want the version locking, just replace `drupal/core-recommended` with `drupal/core`

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to do that. I guess I wait until D10.

Comment: Can you workaround specific packages with [composer aliases](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md)? But yeah, seems like probably not where you want to be anyway.

Comment: D10 has been updated with Symfony 5, but the version of D10 composer pulls doesn't seem to have those changes